# Не получается сделать AJAX запрос

Tags: javascript, ajax, cors

```
$.ajax (
    {
        type: "GET",
        url: 'httpbin.org/bearer',
        dataType: 'json',
        crossDomain: true,
        headers: {
            'Access-Control-Allow-Origin': '*'
        },
        xhrFields: {
            withCredentials: true
        },
        data: {

        },
        success: function(response) {
            console.log(response);
        }
    }
)
```

Делаю запрос к api но, в браузере появляется такая ошибка

```
from origin 'null' has been blocked by CORS policy: Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https.
```

Что я делаю не так и как это исправить?

Comment: Он пишет что запросы между доменами работают по протоколу http и т.д. Попробуйте укажите http:// перед url

Comment: Страничка с которой делается запрос должна быть открыта по протоколу http (или другому из списка). Видимо вы просто открыли файл с диска. Вам нужен веб-сервер